# Polynomial calculation

Tags: polynomials

Determine $m, n$ and $p$ so that the polynomial P defined by
$$P (x)=(3m-2)x^2+(m+2n)x+3m-2n-p$$ is identically zero.
And please help me I'm stuck here. I was absent for the tutoring of this idea and thanks for your time.
So I'm guessing we solve it as
$$3m-2=0; m=\frac23$$
$$2+2n=0; n=\frac26$$
$$3m-2n-p =0; P=\frac43$$
Is this true guys ?

Comment: Have you tried the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) with $a=3m-2,b=m+2n$ and $c=3m-2n-p$ ?

Comment: $3m-2=0, m+2n=0$ etc.

Comment: Yeah i didnt thanks bro

Comment: You don't want to use the quadratic formula. You want all the coefficients to be identically zero as @DougM stated. The quadratic formula would involve $0/0$ type things in this case (and if it didn't, you'd get particular solutions which are zero but $P$ wouldn't be identically zero).

Comment: @Batman Well i didnt understand anything right now im confused how can i solve it then

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Polynomials calaculatung](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2347362/polynomials-calaculatung)

Comment: $P(x)=0\cdot x^2+0\cdot x+0.$$

Answer (score 0):

For this function to be identially zero, we want each coefficient to be $0$:

\begin{align}3m-2&=0\tag{$x^2$ term}\\
m+2n&=0\tag{$x$ term}\\
3m-2n-p&=0\tag{constant term}\end{align}

We now solve this by first finding $m$:

\begin{align}3m-2&=0\\
3m&=2\\
m&=\frac 23\end{align}

Now we can find $n$:

\begin{align}m+2n&=0\\
\frac 23+2n&=0\\
2n&=-\frac 23\\
n&=-\frac{2}{2\times 3}\\
&=-\frac 13\end{align}

Finally, we can find $p$:

\begin{align}3m-2n-p&=0\\
3\times \frac 23-2\times \left(-\frac 13\right)-p&=0\\
2+\frac 23-p&=0\\
p&=2+\frac 23\\
&=\frac 83\end{align}

So, we have \begin{align}m&=\frac 23\\
n&=-\frac 13\\
p&=\frac 83\end{align}